# Making sprite movement smooth when it's move towards an object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, sprite

I'm working on a fish sprite animation. Currently when I add a piece of food then the sprite animation will move forward to eat it. But I am not able to make it swim smoothly toward the food. Sometimes the sprite animation will move up and down till it reach the food.

Here is how the sprite animation is moving towards the food:

```
Fish.prototype.chaseFood = function(index) {
    if (this.xPos > foodArray[index].x + foodWidth) {
        this.speedX = -1 * Math.abs(this.speedX);
    } else if (this.xPos < foodArray[index].x) {
        this.speedX = Math.abs(this.speedX);
    }
    if (this.yPos > foodArray[index].y + foodHeight) {
        this.speedY = -1 * Math.abs(this.speedY);
    } else if (this.yPos < foodArray[index].y) {
        this.speedY = Math.abs(this.speedY);
    }
};
```

Is there anyway to make it swim more smoothly towards the food and not moving up and down towards it.

Comment: The problem is you are always moving by 1 or -1.  If your sprite has to move to the right by 10 units and down by 5 units, it should move to the right with x increasing by twice the rate as y.  I would start by evaluating the slope of the line between the point of the sprite and the object and using the variables to decide what to add to .speedX and .speedY.

Answer (score 1):

I'd calculate angle between the fish and the food and make the fish move towards that angle.

Here are some helper functions to get you going:

```
function distanceBetweenPoints(a, b)
{
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2));
}

function angleBetweenPoints(a, b)
{
    return Math.atan2(b.y-a.y,b.x-a.x)*180/Math.PI;
}
```

Usage:

```
var angle = angleBetweenPoints({ x: fish.x, y: fish.y }, { x: food.x, y: food.y });
```

Then you can do something like:

```
fish.x += Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * 10;
fish.y += Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want your sprite to move in a direct line from one set of coordinates (it's location) to another set of coordinates (the food's location).
[image: http://coolmath.com/algebra/08-lines/06-finding-slope-line-given-two-points-01.htm]

So if your if your x coordinates are a difference of 6 pixels and your y coordinates are a difference of 4, we want to keep the ratio of 6 to 4 when we increase our x and y offset for our happy little fish.

In this case, we could change the program to move x by 1 pixel at a time and then move y by 4/6 pixel at a time and thus go on a path straight towards the goal.  If we were to increase the y by a full pixel, it would arrive directly below the target and then go straight up.  This would be an indirect path and less realistic looking.

Actually I think it would arrive to the left of the goal and then go directly right in the old version if you use the 1 to 1 ratio, but I think you knew what I meant.

I'll try to adapt an example I have to your code:

```
int fishSpeed = 2;
float xOffset = fishSpeed;
float yOffset = fishSpeed;
float xDis = abs(this.xPos-(foodArray[index].x + foodWidth));
float yDis = abs(this.yPos-(foodArray[index].y + foodWidth));
//each offset changes depending on how far it is from goal
xOffset = xOffset * (xDis / (xDis + yDis));
yOffset = yOffset * (yDis / (xDis + yDis));

if(this.xPos > foodArray[index].x) this.xPos+=xOffset;
if(this.yPos > foodArray[index].y) this.yPos+=yOffset;
if(this.xPos < foodArray[index].x) this.xPos-=xOffset;
if(this.yPos < foodArray[index].y) this.yPos-=yOffset;
```

Sorry I couldn't make it work using your example.  I don't know if it will help, but here is a complete .htm file that has a bunny wabbit that is controlled by the mouse and one that is chased directly by another wabbit.  The wabbit will go directly for its goal.  The file needs processing.js in the same directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="lightblue"   style="margin:0;">
<center>
<script src="processing.js"></script>
<script type="application/processing">

void setup(){
    size(screen.width*.9,screen.height*.9);
    blueWabbit = new wabbit(600,600,105);
    pinkWabbit = new wabbit(100,100,100);
    blueWabbit.blue = 255;
    blueWabbit.red = 128;
    blueWabbit.green = 128;

    wabbitSpeed = 5;
    }

void draw() { 

    float xOffset = wabbitSpeed;
    float yOffset = wabbitSpeed;
    float xDis = abs(pinkWabbit.xpos-blueWabbit.xpos);
    float yDis = abs(pinkWabbit.ypos-blueWabbit.ypos);
    xOffset = xOffset * (xDis / (xDis + yDis));
    yOffset = yOffset * (yDis / (xDis + yDis));

    if(pinkWabbit.xpos > blueWabbit.xpos) blueWabbit.xpos+=xOffset;
    if(pinkWabbit.ypos > blueWabbit.ypos) blueWabbit.ypos+=yOffset;
    if(pinkWabbit.xpos < blueWabbit.xpos) blueWabbit.xpos-=xOffset;
    if(pinkWabbit.ypos < blueWabbit.ypos) blueWabbit.ypos-=yOffset;

    if (xDis+yDis<wabbitSpeed){
        for(int a =0;a<20; a++)babyWabbit();
    }
    else background(0,0,0,0);

    pinkWabbit.show();
    blueWabbit.show();
    pinkWabbit.xpos = mouseX;
    pinkWabbit.ypos = mouseY;


    /*
    fill(0);
    text("blue x = "+(int)blueWabbit.xpos,10,10);
    text("blue y = "+(int)blueWabbit.ypos,10,20);
    text("pink x = "+pinkWabbit.xpos,10,30);
    text("pink y = "+pinkWabbit.ypos,10,40);
    text("xOffset = "+xOffset,10,50);
    text("yOffset = "+yOffset,10,60);
    text("xDis = "+(int)xDis,10,70);
    text("yDis = "+(int)yDis,10,80);
    */
    } 


class wabbit { 
    //declare the properties that will be used as variables for the object
    float xpos, ypos, diameter; 
    int red, blue, green;
    //define the parameters for the creation of a new class
    wabbit (float x, float y, float wSize) {  
        xpos = x;
        ypos = y; 
        diameter = wSize;
        //radius = .5 * diameter;
        //make it pink if user did not define colors
        if (!(0>red>256)) red = 255;
        if (!(0>green>256))green = 200;
        if (!(0>blue>256)) blue = 200;
        } 
  void show() { 
    noStroke();
    for(a = diameter; a > 0; a-=5){
        fill(red-a,green-a,blue-a);
        //belly and head
        ellipse(xpos, ypos, a, a); 
        ellipse(xpos, ypos-diameter*.7, a*.7,a*.7);
        //feets
        ellipse(xpos-.2*diameter, ypos+diameter*.4, a*.4,a*.4);
        ellipse(xpos+.2*diameter, ypos+diameter*.4, a*.4,a*.4);
        //ears
        ellipse(xpos-.2*diameter, ypos-diameter, a*.2,a*.8);
        ellipse(xpos+.2*diameter, ypos-diameter, a*.2,a*.8);
        }
  } 
}

void babyWabbit(){
 noStroke();
var red=random(1,255);
var green=random(1,255);
var blue=random(1,255);
var xpos=random(1,width);
var ypos=random(1,height);
var diameter = random(20,80);
    for(var a = diameter; a > 0; a-=5){
        fill(red-a,green-a,blue-a);
        //belly and head
        ellipse(xpos, ypos, a, a); 
        ellipse(xpos, ypos-diameter*.7, a*.7,a*.7);
        //feets
        ellipse(xpos-.2*diameter, ypos+diameter*.4, a*.4,a*.4);
        ellipse(xpos+.2*diameter, ypos+diameter*.4, a*.4,a*.4);
        //ears
        ellipse(xpos-.2*diameter, ypos-diameter, a*.2,a*.8);
        ellipse(xpos+.2*diameter, ypos-diameter, a*.2,a*.8);
        }
}

</script><canvas></canvas> 
</body>
</html>
```